# fill out template sheet when a name in a dropdown menu is selected

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, drop-down-menu, autofill, google-sheets-macros

I have created a grade report Google spreadsheet, but now I'm looking for a way to fill in my template report sheet with the grades from one student. How can I achieve this?

In file 1 I have all the grades of the students. In file 2 I have the template of the grade report. How can I create a dropdown menu in the template grade report that displays all the students and when I click on one of the students automatically fills in all the fields in the grade report?
I now use the importrange function to import the data from the column into the template, but now I need a grade report file for every student. 
It would really be much more efficient than to create one grade report file for every student.

I hope you can help me.

File 1:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12M8W7fARJJZN90wM79U4x8RmcnZ08kFSDcZYnB26HB0/copy

File 2:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13-0qhCudC7EYRgOs2UpbJPRSq2nKoBiG2Md3-U8_U1Q/copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```js
var LIST_WITH_GRADES_ID = 'YOUR_ID';
var LIST_WITH_GRADES_STUDENTS_A1 = 'Rapportoverzicht!B2:Y2';

function onOpenSpreadsheet(e) {
  var students = SpreadsheetApp.openById(LIST_WITH_GRADES_ID).getRange(LIST_WITH_GRADES_STUDENTS_A1).getValues()[0];
  var rangeRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(students).setAllowInvalid(false);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('Rapport!E1').setDataValidation(rangeRule);
}

function onEditSpreadsheet(e) {
  var rapportSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Rapport');
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'E1' && e.range.getSheet().getName() == 'Rapport') {
    var studentCol = findStudentCol(e.range.getValue());
    copyStudentGrades(studentCol);
  }
}

/* Returns 1-indexed student column */
function findStudentCol(student) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(LIST_WITH_GRADES_ID);
  var studentsRange = SpreadsheetApp.openById(LIST_WITH_GRADES_ID).getRange(LIST_WITH_GRADES_STUDENTS_A1);
  for (var col=1; col<=studentsRange.getWidth(); col++) {
    if (studentsRange.getCell(1, col).getValue() == student) 
      return col + studentsRange.getColumn() - 1;
  }
}

function copyStudentGrades(studentCol) {
  var gradesSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(LIST_WITH_GRADES_ID).getSheetByName('Rapportoverzicht');
  var templateSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Rapport');

  templateSheet.getRange(4, 4, 30, 1).setValues(
    gradesSheet.getRange(4, studentCol, 30, 1).getValues());

  templateSheet.getRange(4, 10, 25, 1).setValues(
    gradesSheet.getRange(36, studentCol, 25, 1).getValues());
}
```

You will have to put your grades sheet's ID on the first line, and add this script to the editor of your "template" sheet. You will also need to set `onOpenSpreadsheet` and `onEditSpreadsheet` as installable triggers in order to make it work (see [managing triggers manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)).

### Edit

In order to use two different grade files and import the remarks as well, you can use the following edit of the previous code:

```js
var LIST_WITH_GRADES_ID = 'YOUR_LIST_WITH_GRADES_1_ID';
var LIST_WITH_GRADES_2_ID = 'YOUR_LIST_WITH_GRADES_2_ID';
var LIST_WITH_GRADES_STUDENTS_A1 = 'Rapportoverzicht!B2:AG2';
var NSTUDENTS = 24; // Number of students

function onOpenSpreadsheet(e) {
  var students = SpreadsheetApp.openById(LIST_WITH_GRADES_ID).getRange(LIST_WITH_GRADES_STUDENTS_A1).getValues()[0];
  var rangeRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(students).setAllowInvalid(false);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('Rapport!E1').setDataValidation(rangeRule);
}

function onEditSpreadsheet(e) {
  var currentStudent = e.range.getValue();
  var rapportSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Rapport');
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'E1' && e.range.getSheet().getName() == 'Rapport') {
    var studentCol = findStudentCol(currentStudent);
    copyStudentGrades(studentCol);
    importRemarks(currentStudent);
  }
}

/* Returns 1-indexed student column */
function findStudentCol(student) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(LIST_WITH_GRADES_ID);
  var studentsRange = SpreadsheetApp.openById(LIST_WITH_GRADES_ID).getRange(LIST_WITH_GRADES_STUDENTS_A1);
  for (var col=1; col<=studentsRange.getWidth(); col++) {
    if (studentsRange.getCell(1, col).getValue() == student) 
      return col + studentsRange.getColumn() - 1;
  }
}

function copyStudentGrades(studentCol) {
  var gradesSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(LIST_WITH_GRADES_ID).getSheetByName('Rapportoverzicht');
  var gradesSheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(LIST_WITH_GRADES_2_ID).getSheetByName('Rapportoverzicht');
  var templateSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Rapport');

  templateSheet.getRange(4, 4, 30, 1).setValues(
    gradesSheet.getRange(4, studentCol, 30, 1).getValues());

  templateSheet.getRange(4, 10, 25, 1).setValues(
    gradesSheet.getRange(36, studentCol, 25, 1).getValues());

  templateSheet.getRange(4, 6, 30, 1).setValues(
    gradesSheet2.getRange(4, studentCol, 30, 1).getValues());

  templateSheet.getRange(4, 12, 25, 1).setValues(
    gradesSheet2.getRange(36, studentCol, 25, 1).getValues());
}

function importRemarks(student) {
  var remarksSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(LIST_WITH_GRADES_ID).getSheetByName('opmerkingen rapport');
  var remarksSheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(LIST_WITH_GRADES_2_ID).getSheetByName('opmerkingen rapport');
  var templateSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Opmerkingen');
  var studentRow;

  for (var i=2; i<(2+NSTUDENTS); i++) {
    if (remarksSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue() == student) {
      studentRow = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  templateSheet.getRange('B5').setValue(remarksSheet.getRange(studentRow, 2).getValue());
  templateSheet.getRange('B11').setValue(remarksSheet2.getRange(studentRow, 2).getValue());
}
```

Comment: Hello, I tried to make it work, but I'm still struggling with a few things. 
- Your _ID is the last part of the link after https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d?

Comment: @RikKnijnenburgDaltonschoolO Correct, your ID in this case should be `12M8W7fARJJZN90wM79U4x8RmcnZ08kFSDcZYnB26HB0` (extracted from your original question). Let me know if that works for you. Cheers

Comment: - How can I create a dropdown menu where I can select the student to trigger the script?
- How can I set the triggers right? 
I don't have much experience using these functions. So I'm a little lost here. 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13-0qhCudC7EYRgOs2UpbJPRSq2nKoBiG2Md3-U8_U1Q/edit#gid=1634415010

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12M8W7fARJJZN90wM79U4x8RmcnZ08kFSDcZYnB26HB0/edit#gid=95415556

Comment: and the script editor link: https://script.google.com/d/1M8oBRgYgL5MIMGy88VQFpeulQUVpy8hFc58dMW7qG3y7SQiMNUUFLF87/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @RikKnijnenburgDaltonschoolO The first line of your script should look like this: `var LIST_WITH_GRADES_ID = '12M8W7fARJJZN90wM79U4x8RmcnZ08kFSDcZYnB26HB0'`. Also, you have to set up an onOpen trigger (see my answer). Upon setting it, the dropdown will be created for you. Also, please remember to set up the onEdit trigger too.

Comment: I think it works now! 
I have two more questions. 
1. When the second report is written I have to be able to fill in the data form both reports at once. What is the best approach here? The data from the second report is coming from a different spreadsheet.
2. I have a tab in the report with remarks (opmerkingen). It links to the list with grades tab: opmerkingen rapport. How can I add this field for student 1 (field B2) to the script. 
Thanks a lot for helping me with this!

Comment: Hey @RikKnijnenburgDaltonschoolO, I have edited my answer including code for your other requisites (2 grading files, importing of 'remarks'). Bear in mind that the two grading files must have the same structure. Let me know whether that works for you. Cheers!

Comment: Hey @carless97 It look likes it works only I'm getting an error on line 13: var currentStudent = e.range.getValue(); 
and when I run the function copy studentgrades it gives an error on line 37:
templateSheet.getRange(4, 4, 30, 1).setValues(

But the everything seems to get copied when I choose the student.

Comment: Hey @RikKnijnenburgDaltonschoolO the functions are meant to be ran on triggers, so you should not execute them manually (most of them will just result in errors). Other than that, if you still encounter any impeding issue with it please tell me what information does the error raise, so I can debug it.

Comment: Hey @carlesgg97 Thanks a lot for all the help! Good to know that manually executing the triggers is not a valid method to test if the code works. Everything gets copied now. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is very unlikely that this will work the very first time.  I was not able to copy your sheets so I have not been able to test this at all.  I've written stuff like this before but it usually takes some tweaking to get it to work properly.  I'm also not convinced that the onEdit() section will always complete in 30 seconds but I'm willing to give it a chance but you may have to convert to selecting a semester and then a student and then click a button.

Read the comments:

```
//add this function to an installable onOpen Trigger
function onOpenFunc() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Rapport');
  var slss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("12M8W7fARJJZN90wM79U4x8RmcnZ08kFSDcZYnB26HB0");
  var slsh=slss.getSheetByName("Rapportoversicht");
  var namerg=slsh.getRange(2,1,1,slsh.getLastColumn());
  var cell=sh.getRange(1,2);
  cell.clearDataValidations();
  var rule1=SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .requireValueInRange(namerg)
  .build();//gets student list into drop down
  cell.setDataValidation(rule1);
  var rule2=SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .requireValueInList([1,2])
  .build();//Semester selection 1 or 2
  cell.offset(1,0).setDataValidation(rule2);
}

//This has to be an installable trigger
function onEditFunc(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='Rapport')return;
  if(e.range.getColumn==5 && e.range.getRow()==1 && e.value && e.value!=e.oldValue ) {
    fillInStudentInformation(e.value,e.range.offset(1,0).getValue());  
  }
}

//I am not sure that this will always complete in 30 seconds so you may have to revert to clicking a button after selecting a semester and a student.
function fillinStudentInformation(student,semester) {
  var slss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("12M8W7fARJJZN90wM79U4x8RmcnZ08kFSDcZYnB26HB0");
  var slsh=slss.getSheetByName("Rapportoversicht");
  var hrg=slsh.getRange(2,2,1,slsh.getLastColumn()-1);
  var hA=nrg.getValues()[0];
  var hObj={};
  var lObj={};
  hA.forEach(function(name,i){hObj[name]=i+1;});//column number
  var grdRg=slsh.getRange(4,hObj[student],60,1);
  var lblRg=slsh.getRange(4,1,60,1);
  var grdA=grdRg.getValues();
  var lblA=lblRg.getValues();
  lblA.forEach(function(lbl,i){
    if(lbl && grdA[i]) {
      lObj[lbl]=grdA[i];//object converts from labels to grades
    }
  });
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Rapport');
  var rg1=sh.getRange(4,2,sh.getLastRow()-3,5);
  var vA=rg1.getValues();
  var rg2=sh.getRange(4,8,sh.getLastRow()-3,5);
  var vB=rg2.getValues();
  //left half
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][0] && lObj.hasOwnProperty(vA[i][0])) {
      switch(semester) {
        case 1:
          sh.getRange(i+4,4).setValue(lObj[vA[i][0]]);
          break;
        case 2:
          sh.getRange(i+4,6).setValue(lObj[vA[i][0]]);
          break;
      }

    }
  }
  //right half
  for(var i=0;i<vB.length;i++) {
    if(vB[i][0] && lObj.hasOwnProperty(vB[i][0])) {
      switch(semester) {
        case 1:
          sh.getRange(i+4,10).setValue(lObj[vB[i][0]]);
          break;
        case 2:
          sh.getRange(i+4,12).setValue(lObj[vB[i][0]]);
          break;
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your assistence. I have edited the link. When clicked it automatically creates a copy. I hope this works better for you.

Comment: Okay, thanks I’ll get back to it when I’m on my desktop.